# Action method in Controller is called eternally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having trouble with my site that I am creating. Trying to debug it, I noticed that when I hit F5 to run the site, it keeps creating the website on top of the one created earler, and keeps calling the action methods over and over again, and eventually firefox ends up eating all the CPU. I have noticed that it is this code:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

that causes it. If I remove this code from the View, it works fine. Any idea what might be the problem?

My view looks like this:

```
   @model WebApplication1.Models.IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="pageContentDiv">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem</p>
</div>
```

My Layout looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/OwnedScripts/InitializeUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initUI();
        });        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topMenu">
       <div id="topMenuContentDiv" style="margin-left: 110px;">
           <ul>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roads", "Recs", "Home")</li>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Software", "Software", "Home")</li>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
               <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li> 
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentDiv" id="#contentDiv">
        <div id="decor" style="height: 640px; float: right;">
            <div id="decorPNG" style="background-image: url('../Images/VisualImages/decor.png'); width: 300px; height: 64px;
                float: right; margin-right: -20px; margin-top: 100px;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="logoDiv">
            <h1>QitozNet</h1>
        </div>

        @RenderBody()

      <footer class="footer">
          <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - All rights reserved</p>
          <hr />
      </footer>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Controller looks like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

       public ActionResult Recs()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Temp";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Software()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }        

    }
}
```

The Index method is getting called over and over again, returning in an eternal loop it seems. When debugging it, I kept pressing F10 (step over) for 5 min, and realized that it was just creating the page over again, but on top of the older one, so it ends up duplicating the site

I have also tried to remove the: `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` from the Views, so that they only reside in the: `_ViewStart.cshtml` but no luck

The initGUI script looks like this:

```
    function initUI() {
    $(".topMenu").tabs();
    $("#logoDiv").toggle("slide", { direction: 'left' }, 2000);

    $("#decorPNG").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).draggable({ axis: 'y', containment: "#decor" });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can this be a code in `initUI()` that refreshes page or clicks an action link?

Comment: So it works fine when you remove  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; from your view? But why do you need to write this line? And finally even without writing that line you must be getting that view?

Comment: What does this code do? The InitUI() function?
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initUI();
        });        
    </script>

Comment: You are right. The code that causes the problem is the JS code. It is this part: $(".topMenu").tabs();  where I add Jquery's .tabs() method on my <li> elements. How come this is conflicting with <li>@Html.ActionLink... ?

Comment: There must be some other code in your app which is causing, if above is your real code it should work fibe, do you have any action filter?

Comment: Above is my real code, I c&p it here. I am new to asp.net mvc, so I don't know yet what action filter is. So I guess I don't have any action filter, unless it's there by default.
I must debug some more. But at least now I know about what  to look for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is here:

```
<div class="topMenu">
   <div id="topMenuContentDiv" style="margin-left: 110px;">
       <ul>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Roads", "Recs", "Home")</li>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Software", "Software", "Home")</li>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li> 
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

When you use jQueryUI tab, it uses the anchor tag to load the content into that tab, and then display the content when you click on it.  Your issue is that the `Home` controller `Index` action is in your menu and the default item so you have a recursive loop.

If you really want to use jQueryUI tabs, then you should disable the href `ActionLink` for the current page.  Or you should render `PartialViews` for your `ActionLinks` and use your Home/index as the container.  Then your app would function more like a SPA (single page application).

Here are 2 possible solutions depending on what your aim is:
One way to achieve what I think you're looking for using jQuery UI.  Copy your Index action and View to another name like "Default".  Then change that action and all the other actions to return PartialViews.

```
public PartialViewResult Default()
{
    // do stuff
    return PartialView();
}
```

Then remove any code in your Index action that you don't want to display on all pages.  This now will be your container, and then your tabs will render the partial views of all of those pages.  Your `PartialView` will render the same exact code as before, but without the `_Layout.cs` file.  These will still use the `ActionLink` methods in your `.cshtml` files.

A second approach is to use [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav).  That is the CSS approach, and you can add the css class "active" based on the active page, without making any changes to your ActionResults.

Comment: I will go for the attempt of disabling the href ActionLink for the current page. But if I do this, then how can I make it so that the Action method belonging to that href is called? I have to handle this manually if I disable the ActionLink


I could fx. do <a href="Index.cshtm">Home</a>. But clearly there is an issue here, as I am not able to contact the controller class, and find the proper Action method in there

Comment: It is really bugging me that I can't use JQuery's .tabs() on my ActionLink. If anyone has had the same issue, and found something else to obtain the nice tab look and feel, without coding too much, pleas share :-)

Comment: You can use JQuery's `.tabs()` and `ActionLink()`. If you getting an endless loop, the problem is else where. Usually its the result of using `@Html.Action()` somewhere instead of `@Html.ActionLink()` or `@Url.Action()` (`@Html.Action()` calls a method on a controller to return a view will also contains `@Html.Action()` which in turn calls it again and so on and so on)

Comment: Stephen - The endless loop is because the main page is Home/Index, which contains a Home/Index tab, which renders the entire page again which contains all the tabs...and so on.

Comment: user1960836 - provided a couple possible solutions for you.